# How do I compare 2 models?

Tags: logistic, model-comparison, cox-model, logrank-test

I would like to show that a new biomarker (let's say percent tumor volume reduction at 3 weeks of treatment estimated with automatic methods) performs better than an old one (same measure, but based on manual volume measurements) to distinguish groups or predict outcome. I have these different settings:

1. outcome: progression free survival (PFS) (I have all data, no censoring)

   method:

   a) log-rank test for trends in stratified Kaplan Meier

   b) cox regression (is that a good idea if I have all data?)

   c) logistic regression (binary oucome PFS<6month)
2. outcome: treatment response (3 groups)

   method: pairwise test on means (Mann-Whitney-U)

I'd like to know if there are better approaches for these settings,
and how can I compare the resulting p-values (for the new and for old biomarker). Can I compare them directly, should I run bootstrapping etc.

thanks.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit lost by your question. Normally we compare groups on the basis of outcome (percent tumour reduction?) directly, so I'm not sure why you mention comparing p-values - we get one overall p-value for the comparison. Could you give some more detail about the variables you have rather than the methods you're thinking of?

Comment: Just to be sure to understand: (1) Were these two outcomes collected at the same time (i.e., you have PFS recoded as 0/1 *and* a numerical value for treatment response) and are they available for both methods?; (2) Are you interested in testing the *equivalence* or *non-inferiority* of the new treatment?

Comment: Hi, I don't want to compare groups or treatments. I have a single group and single treatment, but I have 2 ways of estimating a specific biomarker (in the example it is volume change) and want to find out if the new method to establish this marker is better (meaning more predictive power) than the old approach. About PFS it is a time till progression of tumor, I binarize it in 1.c.

Comment: I think @chl's question was - do you have both the automatic method and the manual method for measuring for each case, or do you have one group of cases measured with the automatic method and another group measured with the manual method?  If it's the former its easier to test, but in either case it should be possible.  And I'd go for a bootstrap method.